# Python - Extracting text and summarize multiple file types in directory with Tika and Gensim

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, gensim, apache-tika

My team has been given a task of looking at ~3,800 documents to see which are useful to be rebranded with our updated company branding guidelines.  It will take us forever, so I figured I would at least try to summarize the documents with Gensim, extract some keywords, and write the file name, summary, and keywords to a CSV. I'm doing this in the latest Jupyter Notebook using the Python 3 kernel.

I'm a python newbie, but I've done this in the past by looping through the directory and haven't had an issue.

This time after about 2 or so hours, the memory utilization starts creeping up to around 12GB and stays there for about an hour then returns down to normally fluctuationg between 100-300MB. Then an hour or two later the memory jumps back up and stays there and doesn't seem to process any more files...I left it running for 24 hours.  Being new to Python I'm not familiar with how to debug this and I'm not sure if it is because of my loop, some type of file encoding issues, or just a corrupt file or two in general.

Any help would be extremely greatful.  Code below.

```
#Start java tika server before running

import os, sys, csv
import tika
from tika import parser
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning, module='gensim')
from gensim.summarization import summarize, keywords

# Set path to directory where files are
path = 'C:/Users/john/Desktop/WWS-Local' #directory has 3,800 files of multiple types
os.chdir(path)

exFileTypes = ('.zip', '.jpg', '.mp4', '.msg', '.oft', '.txt', '.png') #Don't care about these file types
with open('C:/Users/john/Desktop/winProcessedFiles.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['File Name', 'Summary', 'Keywords'])
    for file in os.listdir('.'):
        if not file.endswith(exFileTypes):
            try:
                parsed = parser.from_file(file)
                text = parsed["content"]
                text = text.strip('\n')
                text = text.encode('ascii','ignore').decode('ascii')
                summary = summarize(text, word_count=200)
                kw = keywords(text, words=15)
                writer.writerow([file, summary, kw])
            except Exception as e:
                print(file, e)
                writer.writerow([file, e, 'ERROR'])
            finally:
                pass
```

I started doing some basic logging and have been looking at my log file every so often.  My memory usage has spiked and it seems like the document being processed is taking an extremely long time.

I noticed this in the log:

INFO:root:102381-manufacturing-automotive-competitive-assessment-english-letter.pptx parsed in 10.553594589233398s
INFO:gensim.corpora.dictionary:adding document #0 to Dictionary(0 unique tokens: [])
INFO:gensim.corpora.dictionary:adding document #10000 to Dictionary(2545 unique tokens: ['pictur', 'slide', 'titl', 'automot', 'manufactur']...)
INFO:gensim.corpora.dictionary:adding document #20000 to Dictionary(3386 unique tokens: ['pictur', 'slide', 'titl', 'automot', 'manufactur']...)
INFO:gensim.corpora.dictionary:adding document #30000 to Dictionary(3963 unique tokens: ['pictur', 'slide', 'titl', 'automot', 'manufactur']...)
INFO:gensim.corpora.dictionary:adding document #40000 to Dictionary(4335 unique tokens: ['pictur', 'slide', 'titl', 'automot', 'manufactur']...)
INFO:gensim.corpora.dictionary:adding document #50000 to Dictionary(4565 unique tokens: ['pictur', 'slide', 'titl', 'automot', 'manufactur']...)
INFO:gensim.corpora.dictionary:adding document #60000 to Dictionary(4736 unique tokens: ['pictur', 'slide', 'titl', 'automot', 'manufactur']...)
INFO:gensim.corpora.dictionary:built Dictionary(4923 unique tokens: ['pictur', 'slide', 'titl', 'automot', 'manufactur']...) from 66286 documents (total 1009200 corpus positions)

Could this be the cause of the increased memory usage?  And why is it creating multiple dictionaries for this file when it looks like it only creates one dictionary for the other files?